# sp_send_dbmail issue when using variable for subject line

Tags: sql-server

When using a variable for the subject line for a database trigger email, I get the variables back in the subject line but they look like this:

`<i loan_id="6686"><cm cust_name="John Bonham  IIIII"><ld loan_number="5555"><e FAMILIAR_NAME="Test User"/></ld></cm></i>`

Is there a way to clean it up so that it looks better? For instance remove the <>?

```
   SET @subject = 
    CAST ( ( SELECT top 1 i.loan_id,cm.cust_name,  ld.loan_number,  e.FAMILIAR_NAME
              FROM inserted i inner join deleted d on i.LOAN_ID = d.Loan_ID and i.STATUS = 4
                inner join Status s  on i.STATUS = s.Status_ID 
                inner join Loan_Details ld on i.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id and ld.LOAN_ID = d.LOAN_ID
                and ld.STATUS = s.Status_ID
                inner join Employee e on ld.OFFICER = e.EMP_ID
                inner join REL_CUST rc on rc.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id
                inner join Customer_Master cm on cm.CUST_ID = rc.CUST_ID and cm.CUST_ID = rc.REL_TRAN_ID 
                and relationship_id = 1

          WHERE i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and relationship_id = 1 and d.STATUS <>4
          ORDER BY i.loan_id ASC
          FOR XML PATH('') 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) ;
```

Comment: your question states _I get the variables back in the subject line but they look like this_, but I don't see any example of what _they_ look like.  Did you mean to include some additional exhibits before you asked _Is there a way to clean it up so that it looks better?_?

Comment: The output looks like <i loan_id="6686"><cm cust_name="John Bonham  IIIII"><ld loan_number="5555"><e FAMILIAR_NAME="Test User"/></ld></cm></i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to enhance the `FOR XML PATH('')` to pull the actual node values out.

See the following examples (with the results of both at the bottom).

(*Original* represents what you are basically doing now)

(*Updated* uses the enhanced `FOR XML PATH('')` to pull the actual node values out).

```
set nocount on
Declare @T Table (LoanId int, FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100))
insert into @T(LoanId,FirstName,LastName) values 
    (12345,'John','Smith'),(54321,'James','Smith')

declare @subject varchar(100)

--Original statement
SET @subject = cast((
            SELECT TOP 1 LoanId, FirstName, LastName
            FROM @t
            FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) ;

print @subject

--Updated statement
SET @subject = (
            SELECT TOP 1 'LoanId = ' + convert(varchar(10),Loanid) + ',' + 'FirstName = ' + FirstName + ',' + 'Lastname = ' + lastname
            FROM @t
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)');

print @subject
```

---

```
<LoanId>12345</LoanId><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName>
LoanId = 12345,FirstName = John,Lastname = Smith
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! i now get these results 6686John Bonham IIIII5555Jason Starnes in the subject line. Is it possible to add any spacing?

Comment: Try adding some extra concatenation of spaces  - `select col1 + '' + col2 + '' + col3 + ''`

Comment: Thanks I tried that but keep getting errors. Is there anyway to put a static field name in front of each one?

Comment: @JamieBarbery - if you look at my example, you will see I have labels in front of my column values - `FirstName = John, LastName = Smith`

Comment: When I try to put text in front of the field names we get errors in our application.

Comment: SET @subject = 

     (SELECT  
     TOP 1 'LOAN = ' + i.loan_id + ',' 
     --top 1 i.loan_id, cm.CUST_NAME,  ld.loan_number,  e.FAMILIAR_NAME
              FROM inserted i inner join deleted d on i.LOAN_ID = d.Loan_ID and i.STATUS = 4

Comment: @JamieBarbery - I'm sorry my solution isn't working out for you.  If there is a way that you can update your question to include a full working example of the problem (table definitions, sample data, etc.), I might be able to help. It's difficult for me to see all of the stuff on your side of the fence because I can't run your actual query.

Comment: @JamieBarbery - I updated my code example to include a numeric field to be concatenated (LoanId).  You need to make sure you convert any numeric columns to varchar before concatenating them.

Comment: Scott it is working now. Thanks so much for your help!